# Завершение ввода в консоль Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, консоль, ввод

Есть код ввода данных через консоль:

```java
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader =
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
      String line;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
```

Как мне завершить ввод через консоль, если при нажатии <kbd>Enter</kbd> IDEA распознает это не как `null`? Как ввести этот самый `null`? При считывании через файл работает все как надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) возвращает введенную строку за исключением *символов [перевода строки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)*, либо `null` при достижении конца потока, т. е. в данном случае при нажатии на <kbd>Enter</kbd> возвращает пустую строку. Ваш код можно переписать так:

```java
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader =
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    while (line != null && !line.isBlank()) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```